# PL/SQL time segment calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, toad

I need to figure how much time passed between 2 times. For example:

(14:00:00 - 13:15:00) * 24 = **.75**

I need this to later on convert KW to KWh, but that's not the point.

I can not find out how to do this in PL/SQL.

My date/time fields look like this in the DB:

1/23/2010 21:00:00

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Steve

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? The reason for asking is that built in functionality was added at 9i that should be able to make this easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 9i above does this give you the expected result?

```
select extract(hour from numtodsinterval(to_date('14:00:00','HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('13:15:00','HH24:MI:SS'),'DAY'))
||':'|| extract(minute from numtodsinterval(to_date('14:00:00','HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('13:15:00','HH24:MI:SS'),'DAY')) diff
from dual
/

DIFF
------------------

0:45
```

Extract is detailed [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm#SQLRF00639)

and numtodsinterval is detailed [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm#i88258)

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast solution. Now I am strugling with my own data isues I think. I am getting this error: "ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected" - The dateTime field looks like this: 8/12/2009 14:29:59 - I don't get it

Comment: Glad I could help - 

Instead of to_date('14:00:00','HH24:MI:SS')

how about using 

to_date('8/12/2009 14:29:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

I don't know if I have got the month (MM) and the day (DD) in the correct position but you should be able to swap these

Comment: Thanks again, I did just that but the weird thing is if I hardcode the date/time into the function it works, when I get it from the table I got that error. The date is copied from the table, how can that be....anyway, you already help me so much. Thank you again.

Comment: if you run this query: select value
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' what date format do you get back? if it is different to what you expect and the database setting try using ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YOUR DATE FORMAT'

Comment: I don't have toad so if you run this command in sql plus what do you get? 
show parameter nls_date_format

Comment: That did it but now the DIFF = 0.0 - Should be 0.75 - My STart = 8/12/2009 13:15:00 - endtime = 8/12/2009 14:29:59

Comment: Sorry man, I did not properly set the NLS format, after setting it correctly its all good. Sorry about that. This was a great learning experience.

Comment: No worries and again glad I could help!